# Unwanted Line Breaks in Shell Command (from VIM)

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I am trying to run a shell command in VIM using "exe." I have a variable that contains the result of a system call (a pathname)

```
tempName=system('run.sh') "tempname is actually equal to "/path/to/file/tempfile.do"
```

I want to use the variable tempName in another shell command:

```
exe '! cat '.tempName.' >> anotherFile'
```

So what should run is:

```
cat /path/to/file/tempFile.do >> anotherFile
```

but for some reason the " >> anotherFile" part is cut off and only

```
cat /path/to/file/tempFile.do
```

is running. I tried escaping the ">>" characters and the "." which did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work when you type it literally?

```
:execute '!cat /path/to/file/tempFile.do >> anotherFile'
```

If so, then the problem is that `system()` captures the output including the newlines.

One solution is to strip the final newline using `substitute()`:

```
:execute '!cat '.substitute(tempName, '\n$', '', '').' >> anotherFile'
```

Comment: Yep, it works fine if typed literally, and substitute works great. Should have thought of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Note the space after `cat`

```
:exe '! cat '.tempName.' >> anotherFile'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I've been trying (the missing space was a typo). The problem is that Bash cats the file to the screen instead of appending it to "anotherFile." The " >> anotherFile" part doesn't even appear in BASH. The line breaks in the title was because if you echo the command in VIM it breaks it into two lines at the >> which I think may be what is causing the problem.